# how much cardio and weight training per day for beginners

Tags: cardio, strength-training

I am skinny fat , physically bit weak boy [ 26 age ] with 6.1 tall [ 1.83 ] and reduced my body weight from 78 kg [ 171 pounds] to 71 kgs [156 pounds] . still i have some belly and i wanted to eliminate that completely. along with that i want to get some shape and muscle. right now i am doing cardio 60 - 90 minutes per week and i am in calorie deficit diet.

what i want to know is "I want to do strength training also" along with cardio.

So **how much cardio** and **how much strength training** is not **too much** for me ?

may i go with **5 days** [ 30 minutes/day ]  strength training & **3 days** [ 30 minutes/day ] cardio per week ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say go 3 days per week (e.g. M, W, F) of 60min weights. You can do cardio on Tues and Thurs, but not too hard, just light cardio. You need to give your muscles time to recover and build.

Don't worry about the fat. Think of it as an energy store as you are lifting. It will be used up by the muscle you are putting on (as long as your diet is clean, of course).

Answer (score 2):

There are a large number of programs out there aimed at beginners, written by well regarded coaches and trainers, which will give you a decent weight (strength) training program as well as options for cardio.

When you find one you want to try, stick with it. Don't chop and change. Too many beginners change programs every week. Pick one and stick to it.

Something like the New Rules of Lifting series by Alwyn Cosgrove and Lou Schuler would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just eat less calories than you need and put on muscle. Thats not how it works.

If you're a beginner and fairly slim, as your description, the more muscle mass you put on the less you body fat percentage will be, as there will be more muscle and you'll be burning energy too.

You can't cut and bulk at the same time, but you can bulk clean.

More than 30 mins of cardio may not be beneficial if you're trying to add mass. All depends on what you're going for.

You also need to be aware of macronutrients ie, protein, carbs and fat. Just munching down calories is a haphazard way to do it, its not as complicated as it sounds. Theres always a bit of experimentation.

http://www.calculator.net/calorie-calculator.html

Start here ^